# iptables log parser

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, logging

I want a program who feed iptables log and print it in readable form.

This bugs me out:

```
Apr 23 19:36:27 ******* kernel: [ 8195.237958] iptables DROP: IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.102 DST=74.125.232.52 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=5394 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59534 DPT=443 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0
```

Comment: That's as readable as it gets. You probably want some log analysis software to make it pretty, but what information is missing in what is above?

Comment: Yes, I want a pretty human-readable form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) fwanalog "http://tud.at/programm/fwanalog/"

fwanalog is a shell script that parses and summarizes firewall logfiles.

(2) Loggrep

Logrep is a tool for collection and presentation of information from various logfiles including snort, squid, postfix, apache, sendmail, iptables/ipchains and nt eventlogs. HTML-reports, multi dimensional analysis, ssh and graphs are available.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for, in general, is log visualization of some kind.  As @gparent mentioned in his comment, the provided logs are fine--the fields and various flags are clearly marked and legible, which makes searching around for specific fields and values easy.

If you're looking for ways to visualize the data or make it easier to search, you can look into some generic tools like [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com), but I doubt you'll find it any clearer than it is now.